# terminating with uncaught exception of type std::bad_alloc: std::bad_alloc

Tags: c++

The error occurred while reading a file using QFile. The size of file is 1.8GB. The code I used is:

```
QString file_data = QString::fromLocal8Bit(file.readAll()).trimmed() ;
```

The program terminates and gives the error:

```
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type std::bad_alloc: std::bad_alloc
```

Can anyone tell me what I did wrong in the above statement?

Comment: Try using `var file_contents = file.readAll();` as your first line to be sure about where the error happens.  If it happens on that line, then 1.8GB is probably just too big for your environment to read in the entire contents of the file all at once.

Comment: You could try it with a much smaller file to be sure.

Comment: How much memory is installed? And are you compiling your code for 32bit or 64bit? `readAll()` will read the entire 1.8GB into *contiguous memory*, and then `fromLocal8bit()` will decode that into a UTF-16 string that takes up approx 3.6GB of *contiguous memory*. And then `trimmed()` *may* have to duplicate that string into another 3.6GB of *contiguous memory* (only if 1+ characters are actually trimmed). So, before `file_data` can be assigned, your code is already using upwards of 5.4-9GB of memory. A 32bit app won't handle that even on a 64bit OS.

Comment: No self-respecting app should be trying to handle that much data in one big go. You need to break up the data and handle it in smaller manageable chunks.

Comment: Do you even _need_ to load it into memory? Can't you [map()](https://devdocs.io/qt~5.11/qfiledevice#map) it instead?